# BadMethodCallException in View.php line 394: Method [get] does not exist on view

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am getting this error and I can't figure out what is causing the error, can someone help me to solve this?
Here is the code

```
  public function showClassInformation(Request $request)
{
   return response($this->ClassInformation()->get());
}
//===============================================================
public function ClassInformation()
{
    $classes = MyClass::join('academics','academics.academic_id','=','classes.academic_id')
                            ->join('levels','levels.level_id','=','classes.level_id')
                            ->join('shifts','shifts.shift_id','=','classes.shift_id')
                            ->join('times','times.time_id','=','classes.time_id')
                            ->join('batches','batches.batch_id','=','classes.batch_id')
                            ->join('groups','groups.group_id','=','classes.group_id');
    return view('class.classinfo',compact('classes'));
}
```

Comment: `ClassInformation` returns a view that doesn't have a `get` method.

Comment: I have edited the code,you can look at it again